# CASE_SENSITIVE on ORACLE DB

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have a ORACLE DB and when i try inserting "INDIA" and "india" as values into column which is carrying unique constraints on it , it is allowing the value to insert .

It looks like case sensitive options should be enabled in the Db , But not able to figure out where to do that so that it will not allow values with the same name either small / capital letters.

Regards
Chenna B.

---

But I have many columns which need to be updated in the same , so instead of that , can i change parameter at DB level which will not allow of that sort in any columns

Comment: I think you want to insert 'INDIA' and 'india'. Strings are enclosed by single apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a unique function-based index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX countryname_unique ON country (LOWER(countryname));
```

Much better than messing with collations.

Comment: But I have many columns which need to be updated in the same , so instead of that , can i change parameter at DB level which will not allow of that sort in any columns

Comment: Do you really want all unique constraints in your *entire* database to be enforced in a case-insensitive way? Scary. I can only begin to imagine all of the things that would break.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are function based indexes, virtual columns(if you are using 11g version), triggers, application changes...

But there is no simple switch to accomplish what you want.